# How do I use position relative and absolute to position ::after object in a button to make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm working on code for my job - I'm struggling to make this arrow stay inside the button and be responsive for all resolutions and devices. Most of the classes I'm using, and how the HTML is setup is specific to my job, so I can't change really any of it.

I've watched a lot of videos on position relative and absolute, but I'm struggling to apply it with my code.[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7fTC.png)  [correct button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7bG2.png)

My code is the following:

```css
.cn-btn-bn1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: .91px solid #020B24;
  border-radius: 23px!important;
  background-color: #020B24;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.cn-btn-bn1:hover {
  color: #020B24;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.cn-btn-bn1--label {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  font-family: 'InfinitiBrand-Regular';
}

.cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1 {
  padding: 7px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-indent: 18px;
}

.cn-btn-bn1::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #FFF;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cn-btn-bn1:hover::after {
  border-right: 1.5px solid #020B24;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #020B24;
}

.cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1::after {
  width: 11.5px;
  height: 11.5px;
  margin: -1em 0 0 21.7em;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1 {
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: 18px;
  }
  .cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1::after {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: -.92em 0 0 19.9em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="cn-buynow-b1 cn-srp-only" data-vin="{vin}">
    <div class="cn-btn-bn1">
      <span class="cn-btn-bn1--label">personalize payment</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have position relative in .cn-btn-bn1, but I'm not sure if I should put it there, or in cn-buynow-b1. I've done both, but I didn't notice a difference in the arrows position. I've tried removing the display flex, which screwed up the width of the button. I've swapped the position absolute with relative in the ::after, which messed up the height of the button.

The only @media I have setup I did for mobile, but I know it's not perfect.

Comment: If you want a responsive layout, you want to avoid using `position:absolute`.   What specifically isn't working the way you expect in your layout?

Comment: Is it something related to the arrow position that you need to change? Could you describe exactly what is required?

Comment: My apologies, I'm needing the arrow adjust to stay within the button for every resolution/device. I'll edit my post to give a screenshot of how it's supposed to look.
@DanielBeck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the position, In this case I have defined `right: 1em;` to position the element `1em` away from the right border:

```css
.cn-btn-bn1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: .91px solid #020B24;
  border-radius: 23px!important;
  background-color: #020B24;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.cn-btn-bn1:hover {
  color: #020B24;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.cn-btn-bn1--label {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  font-family: 'InfinitiBrand-Regular';
}

.cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1 {
  padding: 7px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-indent: 18px;
}

.cn-btn-bn1::after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #FFF;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cn-btn-bn1:hover::after {
  border-right: 1.5px solid #020B24;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #020B24;
}

.cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1::after {
  width: 11.5px;
  height: 11.5px;
  margin: -1em 0 0 21.7em;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1 {
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: 18px;
  }
  .cn-srp-only .cn-btn-bn1::after {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: -.92em 0 0 19.9em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="cn-buynow-b1 cn-srp-only" data-vin="{vin}">
    <div class="cn-btn-bn1">
      <span class="cn-btn-bn1--label">personalize payment</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it! And I was so close to my answer with the margin I had.